# If electric field outside a parallel plate capacitor is zero then how does it stop charging after some time?

Tags: capacitance

Many sources state that “charging of a capacitor stops when potential difference across a capacitor is equal to that of the battery”. But I cannot understand how this is the reasoning as, an electron travelling from the negative terminal of the battery to the negative plate of a capacitor would only stop(charging process would only stop) when the electric field of the capacitor felt by the incoming electron would be equal to that of the battery. But we know that electric field outside a parallel plate capacitor is 0, then how can the charging process stop???(I have attached an image of what I want to convey)
**1. Blue spheres: electrons**
**2. $E_{in}$: Electric field inside the parallel plate capacitor**
**3. Question marks: Whether such an electric field would even exist as electric field outside a parallel plate capacitor is $0$**
[image]

Comment: You might also ask "Why does the current start in the first place?  The capacitor makes it look like an open circuit."  The answer is:  the E field outside of the capacitor is zero only in an infinite area capacitor.  It is *not* zero in a finite capacitor.  See this nice explanation by [Chabay and Sherwood](https://matterandinteractions.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/AJP-SurfaceCharge.pdf).

Comment: @garyp Thanks but I don't think I will be  able to fully understand(I will give it a try though) the paper you are talking about but I remember reading something related to it. I think it was this, Voltage and Surface Charges: What Wilhelm Weber already knew 150 years ago. And yeah, practically the capacitor would not be inifinite area, that did not come in my head.

Comment: @garyp So if an infinite area charged PPC is connected to an uncharged capacitor, no charge will flow between them?

Comment: Interesting question.  There are still fields due to the battery and induction in the plates of the small capacitor.  I don't know the answer, but it would seem that in an idealized situation no charge would flow.  I welcome a better response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as, an electron traveling from the positive terminal of the battery to
> the positive plate of a capacitor...

You have it backwards. Electrons are pulled off the positive plate at the positive terminal of the battery making the positive plate more positive and supplied to the negative plate by the negative terminal of the battery making the negative plate more negative.

> ...would only stop(charging process would only stop) when the electric
> field of the capacitor felt by the incoming electron would be equal to
> that of the battery.

The charging process stops when the potential difference between the capacitor plates equals the potential difference between the battery terminals. Missing from your diagram is the resistance that always exists between the battery emf and the capacitor. While the capacitor is charging there is a voltage drop across that resistor so the voltage across the capacitor is less than the battery voltage during charging. Eventually the capacitor voltage equals the battery emf and charging current stops.

> But we know that electric field outside a parallel plate capacitor is
> 0, then how can the charging process stop???(I have attached an image
> of what I want to convey)

The electric field is in the wires connecting the battery to the capacitor, not in the space outside the capacitor. The charging stops when the capacitor voltage equals the battery voltage current stops.

> I do know that charging stops when battery voltage equals that of
> capacitor voltage, but I don't understand how that would be even
> possible. " not in the space outside the capacitor" Okay, but then is
> the electric field due to the parallel plate capacitor inside the
> wires zero?? Else how would the motion of electron/charging process
> stop.?

First of all, the direction of the electric field is by convention the direction of the force that a positive charge would experience if placed in the field. Although you are discussing the flow of electrons, conventional current is defined as the flow of positive charge and not electrons.

From the perspective of conventional current, the positive terminal of the battery supplies positive charge to the positive plate of the capacitor making in more positive and the negative terminal of the battery removes positive charge from the negative plate making it more negative.

Now take the wire connecting the positive terminal of the battery to the positive capacitor plate. The electric field in the wire produced by the positive terminal of the battery is directed towards the positive capacitor plate. On the other hand, the electric field produced by the positive plate of the capacitor ***in the wire*** (not in the space outside the capacitor) is directed towards the positive terminal of the battery. When the voltage across the capacitor equals the battery voltage, these fields in the wire are equal and opposite for a net field of zero and no longer any force on the charge in the wire. The current stops.

Hope this helps.

Comment: *"as, an electron traveling from the positive terminal of the battery to the positive plate of a capacitor"* I don't even know why I typed that(sigh..) (I will be editing that out), I do know that charging stops when battery voltage equals that of capacitor voltage, but I don't understand how that would be even possible. *" not in the space outside the capacitor"*  Okay, but then is the electric field due to the parallel plate capacitor inside the wires zero?? Else how would the motion of electron/charging process stop.?

Comment: @Rishi I have updated my answer to respond.

Answer (score 0):

> Many sources state that “charging of a capacitor stops when potential difference across a capacitor is equal to that of the battery”.

Those sources are correct.

> an electron travelling from the negative terminal of the battery to the negative plate of a capacitor would only stop(charging process would only stop) when the electric field of the capacitor felt by the incoming electron would be equal to that of the battery.

You may be confusing electric $\vec{E}$ field with voltage. In the absence of a time varying magnetic field, the electric field is the *gradient* of the voltage.

$$\vec{E} = -\nabla V$$

Current will stop at any point in the wire (and charge will accumulate there) when $\vec{E} = 0$ at that point, or when there is no voltage gradient. Not "when the electric field of the capacitor felt by the incoming electron would be equal to that of the battery"

> But we know that electric field outside a parallel plate capacitor is 0

First of all, not quite true. The electric field in the air around a capacitor is small, but not zero. A charged capacitor forms an electric dipole. But importantly for this case, the electric field *in the leads of the capacitor* become 0 only when the potential difference (voltage) at a capacitor plate is equal to the voltage of the battery terminal it is connected to. That is, the electric field becomes 0 in the wire when there is no voltage gradient.

> then how can the charging process stop???

As charge accumulates in a capacitor plate, it induces a $\vec{E}$ field in the wire counter to that induced by the battery. When the algebraic sum of these two $\vec{E}$ fields becomes 0, current will stop.